# How do I display HTML code (entities) on a web page?

Tags: html

how do you write html code so the user and see it on a webpage (like a how-to for html)

Comment: funny comment, but he's 16.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

encode your html entities:

```
< … &lt;
> … &gt;
& … &amp;
" … &quot;
(' … &apos; xml, not html. see comments)
```

you might also want to use

```
<pre><code>
here comes your preformatted and escaped &lt;html&gt;-code
</code></pre>
```

to have your code monospaced and preserve whitespaces

Comment: doesn't <verbatim> give you the same? i thought <pre> will still expand any html tags found within?

Comment: &amp;apos; isn't supported by IE because it isn't a valid character entity in HTML. The list of HTML character entities is at http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/entities.html and doesn't include it. It is specified in XML 1.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#syntax

Comment: @Rob: What do you mean by "expand"?  In general, there is *no* section of html that is not escaped - not even script tags or style tags (browsers will generally try to to repair missing escaping as best they can though - and a long time ago).

Comment: @ rob wells: there is no such tag as `<verbatim>`
@ nickfitz: see <http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-predefined-ent>. looks like &apos; :P

Comment: @knittl: if you're programmatically encoding illegal codepoints, it is possibly simpler to use numeric entity references, whether decimal or hexadecimal - and you won't run into details like apos being html 5 or xml but not html 4.

Comment: @ eamon: using builtin functions like php’s htmlspecialchars solves the problem perfectly :) (but yeah, i got html and xml confused)

Comment: @knittl: HTML is not XML, and &apos; is not an HTML entity. _XHTML_ allows &apos; because it _is_ XML, but IE doesn't support XHTML, so it doesn't support &apos; See the XHTML 1.0 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_16

Comment: @knittl: Oops, so I see - sorry to nag ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use HTML character entities `&lt;` and `&gt;` in place of the < and > symbols so they aren't interpreted as HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid issues with `&apos;`, use `&#39;`.