# Prevent MySQL SELECT result via web-interface from interpreting html tags in the data

Tags: mysql

I only have a web-page interface to issue SQL commands to query the database.  (A simple text-box to input SQL and a 'Submit' button)

I want to dump the table containing the product data, which includes name, price, description etc. and the description field contains HTML tags.

The problem is the HTML gets interpreted by the web browser in the result, as the result come in a table in a standard web page. How do I truthfully dump the data?

One way I could think of is:

```
SELECT name,price, HEX(description) FROM products
```

But is there an easier way? I'd like to keep the dumped data in Excel for backup. There isn't an UNHEX() in Excel to decode the hex string.

Or is there an even better way?

Comment: See this [similar question][1] on escaping html characters.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394617/how-do-i-display-html-code-entities-on-a-web-page

Comment: My goal is to 'dump' the table for off-line backup. So I'd like to get the data as they're presented in the database. Escaping the HTML might work but a 'clean' method would be even better. (i.e. not fiddling with the content of the table)

Comment: Please could you describe your setup. Normally you would run the CLI tool mysqldump, or any number of client tools like phpMyAdmin, any number of ide, or thick clients. Is there a reason why you can only access the db through a web client? If this really is your only choice, the fact that the browser interprets it as html is irrelevant if you want to just look at the source. For example, you could use wget to get the source and save it to file.