# How to echo html tags using PHP

Tags: php, echo

I want to actually print the HTML tags on the screen. I am not getting how to escape the HTML tags.

**Expected Output**

```
<div>Hey, you can see the div tag on the screen.</div>
```

The `div` tags shouldn't be taken in as HTML tags instead I want to print them on the screen. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean `echo "<div> bla bla </div>"` ?

Comment: @Sentencio No, If I do this I will not be able to see '<div> bla bla </div>'. Instead I will just see ' bla bla '.

Comment: Yes, what you want is **escaping the HTML tags**. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1394617/216084 . Also, you don't need to do it manually - as suggested in answers explore [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: You can do this &lt;div&gt; bla bla bla &lt;&frasl;div&gt;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<div>Hey, you can see the div tag on the screen.</div>');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

like,

```
echo htmlentities( '<div>Hey, you can see the div tag on the screen.</div>');
echo htmlspecialchars( '<div>Hey, you can see the div tag on the screen.</div>');
```

Comment: Thanks I was unaware of that function.

Comment: @NavneetSaini and that's why you should refer [this](http://php.net/) or atleast [this](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

As seen [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text) you can use the [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function.

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<div>Hey, you can see the div tag on the screen.</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by using `strtr()`.

```
    <?php   
    $input =  '<div>Hey, you can see the div tag on the screen.</div>';
    $output = strtr($input, Array("<" => "&lt;"));
print $output;
    ?>
```