# generate code using form button and then display generated code on page

Tags: php, html

I have two file code_generator.html. which takes input as a image url and landing url  when i click on submit button it calls code_created.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action ="code_created.php" method ="post">
        Image : <input type ="text" name ="image">
        Landing Url : <input type ="text" name="landingurl">
            <input type= "submit">
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

I want to show generated code as below on web page

```
<div id='banner-img' style='display:none;text-align:center' onclick='landing()'><img style='text-align:center' id='bannerImage'/>
    <img id='t'/>
    <img id='trackeridImg' style='display:none;width:0px;height:0px'/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                function showAd() {
                document.getElementById('banner-img').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('bannerImage').setAttribute('src',IMAGE URL SUBMITTED FROM HTML FILE);
</script>
```

problem is that webpage is not showing that code generated code ,webpage  is rendering that code , I want to only show that generated code.

1-how to do it using html and php

2-is my approach is right

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394617/how-do-i-display-html-code-entities-on-a-web-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use  tag to show HTML entities You need to encode all
2. Your HTML entities like < => < like way.
3. Also you can show a text area in which all those HTML code need to echo, it will not execute your code simply it will print it.