# Escaping an html entity inside of html

Tags: html, mysql, escaping, html-entities

I have created a drop down where I want either blank, `&reg;` , or `&trade;` to be inserted into my db field.

```
        <select name="copyright_symbol" id="copyright_symbol">
            <option value='' {if !isset($product->copyright_symbol or $product->copyright_symbol == '')}selected="selected"{/if} >{l s='None'}</option>
            <option value='&reg;' {if $product->copyright_symbol == '&reg;' }selected="selected"{/if} >{l s="reg"}</option>
            <option value='&trade;' {if $product->copyright_symbol == '&trade;' }selected="selected"{/if} >{l s="trade"}</option>

        </select>
```

This automatically converts my value to the symbol ® or ™.  I dont want to save the symbol, I want the literal characters in the database.  Any thoughts on escaping the html entity?  Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display HTML code (entities) on a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394617/how-do-i-display-html-code-entities-on-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1):

If a character has special meaning in HTML and you want it to be treated as data instead of having that special meaning then you represent it as an entity.

So if you want `&` to mean *an ampersand* instead of *start of an entity*, then represent it as an entity: `&amp;`

```
value='&amp;reg;'
```

Comment: I tried this but the database field still has the symbol

Comment: It displays properly now in the html side but not when I view field in mysql

Comment: That's because MySQL shows you the text and HTML shows you what happens when you parse the text as HTML.

Comment: It is saving the symbol into the mysql field.  I want `&trade;` in the db field, not ™

Comment: @Trey — If you do what I said, then it will send `&reg;` to the server. Unless you parse it as HTML (or do something like stick it in an HTML document and then give that to the browser to parse), it will remain `&reg;`.

Comment: No idea why I cant get this to work.  Ive reverted to using `{if $product->copyright_symbol[1] == "®"}`